# Win8.1: When logged in with my default MS account many account options don't seem to work

Tags: windows, user-accounts, administration, microsoft-account, windows-8.1-upgrade

So I'm one of those idiots who upgraded to 8.1 allowing MS to grab a really old Hotmail account which is now my default admin account (sigh).

Now I am having various account settings issues like:

I can't disconnect my MS account via the Account settings. This was so I could eventually hook up my desired MS account to Win 8.1.

I also can't seem to add new accounts from `Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Accounts`. And various account settings buttons in the `Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change User Account Settings` etc.

I had to use netplwiz to finally add a local Admin account.

What is going on?